# OptaPlanner: deliveryman going from multiple suppliers to customers

Tags: optaplanner

I'm new to OptaPlanner, and seen how some problems can be solved fairly easily by modifying from the very useful sets of example. I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to model my problem.

I have a group of deliverymen, and their job is to deliver supplies from multiple suppliers to multiple customers. The tricky part is that the customers requirements and suppliers supplies are range values that varies from month to month. And I also have the option to hire temp deliverymen if the supplies and demands of the month is too high. End result is to maximize profit for each month.

What category of optimization problem am I facing, and I'm struggling to find the best way to model this problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Put in a number of temp deliverymen as normal deliverymen with a boolean temp=true, and have your score constraints penalize those more (I presume a higher soft weight as the soft score will be your profit).

This is basically the pickup and delivery variation of the VRP example. Some of our users have adjusted the VRP example to this already (see some of the other questions here on stackoverflow tagged with optaplanner). Basically the trick is to write a score constraint that understands that the "load" of a vehicle changes through its route (but it should always be less than its "capacity").

You can schedule 1 month (or 1 week or less or 2 months or more) at a time, but you can also do "continuous planning" (if months affect each other like in nurse rostering, but I doubt that's the case here) (if so, see the optaplanner video on youtube) to plan a window.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey! Can you point out to me some examples which I can read? There's many many posts of Optaplanner and after scanning around for a while, I still can't find that "pickup and delivery variation".

Comment: I found the Bicycle Messenger example, which has ideas in it that is relevant to my situation.

Regarding the pickup and delivery, I think there is a need to change three things during planning. First is the load of the vehicle as you mentioned after every pickup or delivery. Second is supplies at the supplier which has to decrease every time any vehicle picks up supplies from it. Third is the demand at the customers will decrease too after any successful delivery is made. How can I make sure that all these variables are updated correctly during the planning?

Comment: With a shadow variable (see docs "Planning variable listener").

Comment: I just notice another problem, VRP assumes that each location will only be visited once. In my situation I'm trying to allow multiple visits to each location, until supplier runs out of supplies or customer's demands have been met. So besides changing the Standstill and Customer to have an array of vehicles, what else do I need to change?